# Regex help transforming Hexcodes and HTML snippet to Array and and simple list

Tags: c#, html, regex, notepad++

In the section below from the [FA cheatsheet](http://bit.ly/1TcA0vU), I am trying to convert this to *an array* and *a simple text file* using notepad++ to scrape the [following FA page as source or direct HTML copy](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).

- First, I used the TexFx Plugin and it wont match the braces under TextFx->Quick options, which one should I try.
- Second using help here on S.O., I also tried `find: ^.*(fa-[^\s]*).*
  replace: \1` but since the copy-paste to NP++ [from from the fa cheatsheet](http://bit.ly/1TcA0vU) ended up in one-long line... the `^.` did not work.

  1. how to transform to -> 2D array, so I need to get CSV of 2 columns `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">`, and `<i class="fa fa-bank"></i>`
  2. how to transform to -> simple text list with one description per line

  `fa-tumblr-square
   fa-bank 
   ...`

Please help me understand the regex snippet or the tool option whichever works is fine.

---

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
  <i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
  fa-tty      
  <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf1e4;]</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
  <i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
  fa-tumblr      
  <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf173;]</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
  <i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
  fa-tumblr-square      
  <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf174;]</span>
</div>
```

Edit 1:
@ShellFish Here is what I get, it shows nothing matched on using the regex with and withour newline option `\(. \)\(fa[^ ]*\)\([^ ]*\)` in the Replace I tried space and html comment as well ...
[image: Here is what I get nothing matched on <code>\(. \)\(fa[^ ]*\)\([^ ]*\)</code>]
Regex result on the Div list - does not match
[image: Regex result on the Div list - does not match]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Creating the HTML list

### awk

You could use this using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). First copy the site content in a text file. Then execute following script:

```
BEGIN {
    # set record separator to a space, file is split in records
    RS = " "
    # separate print variables using a double quote
    OFS = "\""
}
# if record (string in between spaces) is the word alias
$0 ~ "(alias)" {
    # skip this line and make sure line number isn't counted
    NR = NR - 1
    getline
}
# print if the record number is 1, 4, 7 (i.e. a symbol)
NR % 3 == 1 {
    print "<div class=", "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3", ">"
    # $1 contains first field which is the entire record
    print "  <i class=", "fa fa-fw", ">" $1 "</i>"
}     
# print lines 2, 5...
NR % 3 == 2 {
    print "  " $1
}   
# analogous for lines 3, 6, 9 ...
NR % 3 == 0 { 
    # sub amp
    sub (/&/, "&amp;", $1)
    print "  <span class=", "muted", ">" $1 "</span>"
    print "</div>\n"
}
```

The comments should make the script clear. You can use it as following:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
```

where `file` is the path to the file with the site content and `script.awk` contains above code.

Example usage:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file | head -n 11
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
  <i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
  fa-adn
  <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf170;]</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
  <i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
  fa-align-center
  <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf037;]</span>
</div>
```

### notepad

1. First remove all aliases from the file, look for

   ```
    (alias)
   ```

   and remove all occurrences (including the leading space).
2. Look for the following pattern in the file:

   ```
   (. )(fa[^ ]*)([^ ]*)
   ```

   this matches exactly one item from the list. Replace this with the following string:

   ```
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">\r\n<i class="fa fa-fw">$1</i>\r\n$2\r\n<span class="muted">$3</span>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n
   ```

   Here `$i` resembles the i-th group captured in the regex. A group is a regex in between `(` and `)`. Perhaps you have to access the groups using `\i` if this doesn't work. The new replacement string becomes:

   ```
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">\r\n<i class="fa fa-fw">\1</i>\r\n\2\r\n<span class="muted">\3</span>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n
   ```
3. substitute the amps, look for `&` and sub by `&amp;`

## Creating Item List

Creating this list can be done from either the [html](/questions/tagged/html) list of the copied file. Both times you simply need to grab `(fa[^ ])*`. This can be done for the one-line file as follows:

1. Remove alias again (see above).
2. Search pattern:

   ```
   . (fa[^ ]*)[^ ]*
   ```

   and replace for `\1\r\n` or `$1\r\n` if that doesn't work.

## Creating `div` lines

To create the `div` lines simply match `(. fa[^ ]*[^ ]*)` and replace it with `\1\r\n` or `$1\r\n` if the backslash doesn't work. This will place newlines after each `div` entry.

Comment: appreciate the answer. However, I only have to do this on win and I have Notepad++ on win, and no `awk` on  win machine... I am trying to incorporate this into my build process.

Comment: Does [tag:notepad] allow substitution using [tag:regex] and backreferences?

Comment: notepad++ does https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ - the win Notepad is cr@p - I found an AWK scriptwriter online trying that now...  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_awk_online.php

Comment: @aggie I added a solution for notepad++, should work I think.

Comment: tried it...  doesnt match for the regex, I pasted a picture above.    I tried it on both the div code _and_ this..                                                                     ` fa-adjust [&#xf042;]  fa-adn [&#xf170;]  fa-align-center [&#xf037;]  fa-align-justify [&#xf039;]  fa-align-left [&#xf036;]  fa-align-right [&#xf038;]  fa-ambulance [&#xf0f9;]  fa-anchor [&#xf13d;]  fa-android [&#xf17b;]  fa-angellist [&#xf209;]  fa-angle-double-down [&#xf103;] `  - trying to scrape this page http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: @aggie Try now, on the single line pasted from the site. Groups are captured using `()`, I escaped them.

Comment: its matching now, but removing fragments and leaving incomplete html like                                             `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <i class="f          
      <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf07e;]</span>
    </div>`     
    
    `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <i class="f          
      <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf07d;]</span>
    </div>`  . can you show me how get rid of the <span> tags and its content _for some odd reason the span html doesnt paste well here_ . If you can show me how to remove the span muted content/tag I can mark this close

Comment: @aggie Yes my mistake, I forgot a `span` element. Try again, I'll update in a minute!

Comment: @aggie, please elaborate on your desired output. For each process, supply a sample input file and a sample output file.

Comment: want 2 lists     -          1) since there is a 1-1 corresponding <div> to nested <i>, I want to flatten this and put them each on 1 row with 2 columns for 2dArray, i.e. a `DivColumn` and `IconColumn`.        -           2) and also _one_ simple vertical list `fa-bank` and `fa-ball` etc from inside the icons. you can see the list here http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: You need to give an example of the first list, give a file containing at least three lines. I'll add the second one to the answer now.

Comment: formatting is lost - please see view source  on the previous cheatsheet link...  `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <i class="fa fa-fw">&#xf170</i>
      fa-adn
      
      <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf170;]</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <i class="fa fa-fw">&#xf037</i>
      fa-align-center
      
      <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf037;]</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <i class="fa fa-fw">&#xf039</i>
      fa-align-justify
      
      <span class="muted">[&amp;#xf039;]</span>
    </div>`

Comment: Where are the newlines in that string? Do you simply wish to put each entire `div` on a separate line? If so simply sub `\r\n([^\r])` for `\1`.

Comment: the SO markdown formatting took out the new lines after each div. But the new lines are after the new div - for now I used excel to get to the answer... but I need a longer term soln to build on